# How do I create a cron job that will run everyday at 12:20am?

Tags: macos, shell, cron

I am trying to write a cron job on my Mac OS X machine that will run a Ruby script at 12:20am everyday.

This is what I need to run but I don't know the syntax or the command to use on the Mac:

```
/usr/bin/ruby /Users/tamer/scripts/sftp.rb
```

I read about doing `crontab -e` but do I need to do something afterwards?

Answer (score 43):

The crontab for "everyday at 12:20am" is

```
20 0 * * *
```

The whole line in crontab would then be

```
20 0 * * * /usr/bin/ruby /Users/tamer/scripts/sftp.rb
```

Answer (score 11):

The crontab entry should look like:

```
20 0 * * * /usr/bin/ruby /Users/tamer/scripts/sftp.rb
```

This assumes that you don't need any other environment variables to make it all work.  If you do need other variables, then create an environment-setting shell script which then executes the Ruby program and script.

To submit the job, I usually use:

```
crontab -l > x3
echo  "20 0 * * * /usr/bin/ruby /Users/tamer/scripts/sftp.rb" >> x3
crontab < x3
rm x3
```

Comment: wouldn't you just use `crontab -e` to edit the crontab config file (in place of using the x3 temp file)?

Comment: @snowbound: Maybe, but only if I knew/remembered the option was there, and if I wanted to do interactive editing.  If I was scripting it, apart from using a better temporary file name (from `mktemp` for example), I'd probably do it as shown.  Or, since I normally keep my `crontab` entry under source control, I would edit the master version of the file and resubmit that after checking in the change.

Comment: your approach also has the advantage of being able to be called programmatically by another script :D